# Java client for Mosquitto

Tags: java, client, mqtt

1).Is it legal to use wmqtt.jar with Mosquitto broker for Android application?

2).Are there any other java client library for Android to connect to Mosquitto broker?

Note:It is an intranet application and no Internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download page for wmqtt.jar (ia92.zip) states:

> Please read the license file that accompanies the SupportPac to determine if you want to use it. No Proof of Entitlement is required to use this SupportPac.
>
> This release contains important additional terms (entitled "Redistribution Information") that allow Other Equipment Manufacturers and others, to re-distribute this SupportPac function as part of a product. Please read the terms contained in the License Information file (Cat3OEM_Lic_en.txt) included in the program .ZIP file. No Proof of Entitlement is required for this SupportPac.

I suggest you do what it says! I don't know of any other Java MQTT clients.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I cannot find the Cat3OEM_Lic_en.txt but I found LA_en. And saw this : "You may 1) use the Program up to the level of use specified in the PoE and 2) make and install copies, including a backup copy, to support such use. The terms of this license apply to each copy You make. You will reproduce all copyright notices and all other legends of ownership on each copy, or partial copy, of the Program.". But you mentioned in above- No PoE is required. So does it mean I can use if for free?

Comment: I presume so, but you should check with a lawyer to be sure.

Comment: Thx. Btw, is your mosquitto free?

Answer (score 5):

There are new Java clients listed on the [mqtt.org site Software page](http://mqtt.org/software) now. You should have a look to see whether they might meet your needs.

The recommended Java client for MQTT is now the [Eclipse Paho](http://eclipse.org/paho) client.

Comment: Morgan if you have an issue I recommend you open a bug on Eclipse Bugzilla rather than making unproductive comments here.

Comment: I've just spent some time playing with paho and it seems to open and maintain 3 threads for every active maintained connection. We need to hold open a large number of connections so this doesn't really work for our use case.